How do I use aliases in the "sh -c" command?
I tried "sh -c [some alias]" but that didn't work, whereas running it directly was fine
~/.bashrc:
alias ll=" ls -alF "

There is the same problem in zsh, and technically I mainly want to solve the problem in zsh, and the result is the same in bash。

The result is "sh: 1: [alias]: command not found".
In zsh it is "zsh:1: Command not found: [alias]"

Is it working on bash but not zsh?

Neither zsh nor bash works.

I use "zsh -c" to execute commands in zsh.

Why do you want do use an alias like this?!

I want to use aliases when I use editors like Vim/Helix. Like alias comcpp="clang++ -Wall -std=c++17 -O2"

Please to all: Forget about alias. This is an obsolete legacy feature with lots of pitfalls and quirks. It only exists for backward compatibility with 35+ years old systems and scripts. Use functions instead.

It should work by using $() instead of back ticks.
Please to all: Forget about back ticks!

When you use sh, you don't execute bash, you are executing sh. For running a bash, do bash -c.

@LéaGris : Of course aliases are unnecessary and hopelessly outdated, but they  give a flavour of antiquity, which some people find charming, an alias, and I wouldn't forbid someone to use them, if s/he loves them so much.

@user1934428 This place is about people getting help solving code problems.When a good chunk of the problems are caused by an obsolete feature like alias. It is therefore perfectly appropriate to advise against the use of aliases, especially as replacing them with functions saves volunteers' time to help with problems that are not linked to the use of obsolete methods, and allows beginners to invest their learning efforts more effectively. Now if the poster had specified he needed to work on antique shell without functions, it would have justified spending time to help. Nostalgia is OT here.

@LéaGris : Sadly you have got a point here ....

@AlohaHenry : The error message alias not find is because you were not using bash. POSIX shells don't allow aliases. But as Lea Gris already pointed out: You shouldn't use aliases anyway.

@user1934428 I’m not defending aliases, but why do you say ’POSIX shells don't allow aliases’? That doesn’t seem to be true.

@Biffen: Indeed, it seems so. I don't use interactive POSIX shells anyway, so I was not aware of this. And now I realize that the OP hasn't got a command not found for alias, but a command not found for [alias], which is of course something different and makes more sense.


You shouldn't expect sh to ever load .bashrc.
bash only loads .bashrc for interactive shells.

As such, you could use
bash -i -c 'll'

The -i forces the shell to be interactive.
If you want to keep using sh, you'll need replicate your aliases as functions in .profile. But be careful against creating functions with the same name as common tools (e.g. ls) in a non-interactive shell.

Your 2nd point should be ".... for interactive non-login shells". See INVOCATION in man bash.

@user1934428, No. What you say is also true, but adds needless and misleading detail.

More specifically, you're right that .bashrc only directly loaded by bash for interactive non-login shells. This doesn't contradict what I said. And it's also misleading because .bashrc is usually indirectly loaded for interactive login shells too. This is because it's common to load .bashrc from .bash_profile for interactive shells. So, in effect, .bashrc is loaded for interactive login shells too. But none of this is relevant here since we're not dealing with login shells. Adding all this to the answer would be a distraction.

I don't know what others are doing (and hence don't know to what extent it is "common"), but I would object against loading .bashrc unconditionally from .bash_profile. What makes sense (IMHO) is to have all settings which makes sense in an interactive shell in a separated file (let's call it .bash_interactive), and source this file from (1) .bashrc, and (2) from .bash_profile only, if it is an interactive loginshell (i.e. I would test the variable $- for deciding what to do). With this, we can keep the interactive and non-interactive settings apart.

for bash: use shopt
for zsh: edit ~/.zshenv and use function instead of alias

For bash you also use functions instead of alias. You must all forget about alias. This is an obsolete legacy feature for backward compatibility with 35+ years old systems and scripts.
